# Spring Data JPA - Find objects by nested object property

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I've implemented a flexible search REST API based on this [article](http://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-specifications).

That API works great except the one moment. When I want to find an object by some nested property, then JPA can't find anything.

For example, a have Order model like this (cutted version):

```
@NotNull
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "date")
private Date date;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "delivery_price")
private Double price;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "status")
private String status;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
private User user;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "courier_id")
private User courier;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "address_from_id")
private Address addressFrom;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "address_to_id")
private Address addressTo;
```

Controller request:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getOrders(@RequestParam(value = "search", required = false) String search,
                                   Pageable pageable) {
    OrderSpecificationsBuilder builder = new OrderSpecificationsBuilder();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+?)(:|<|>)(\\w+?),");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(search + ",");
    while (matcher.find()) {
        builder.with(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2), matcher.group(3));
    }

    Specification<Order> spec = builder.build();

    Page<Order> orders = orderService.findAll(spec, pageable);
    Page<OrderDto> ordersDtos = orders.map(OrderDto::toDto);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(ordersDtos, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Specification classes are here [on Github.](https://github.com/atereshkov/Diber-backend/tree/master/src/main/java/com/github/handioq/diber/repository/specification)

The entire code is available here [on Github.](https://github.com/atereshkov/Diber-backend/tree/master/src/main/java/com/github/handioq/diber)

So I wanna find the order with courier id 10, for example.

I use a request like **/api/v1/orders?search=courier.id:10** and there are no results found.

As I understand, SearchCriteria is implemented in a sort of universal API, and I have no idea why it works only for this simple queries like search=price:10 and so on.

Comment: One thing I noticed is your `OrderSpecification` implements `Specification<User>` instead of `Specification<Order>`

Comment: Go to your OrderRepository and add a Method: Page<OrderDto> findByOrderDtoNAMEOFTHEVARIABLENAMEINORDERDTO(VARIABLEOFORDERDTOYOUWANTTOADD s, Pageable p)

Comment: @JoeChiavaroli thanks! I'll fix it.

Comment: @Noixes, as I understand, the repository should work not with DTO objects, and as u can notice, I also try to use findAll method with specification and pageable requests.